# Getting Cannot resolve path parameter (jobid) when deploying a Flink job in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink

I am getting an exception in the Job Manager log while deploying a job in Kubernetes using flink-on-k8s-operator.

The job deploys successfully eventually but it is rather annoying to see the below exception in the log 3 times before it deploys.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks

Pauli

```
2022-02-08 23:52:20,200 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager [] - Starting the resource manager.
2022-02-08 23:52:20,531 TRACE org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.job.JobsOverviewHandler [] - Received request /jobs/overview.
2022-02-08 23:52:20,608 TRACE org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.job.JobsOverviewHandler [] - Starting request processing.
2022-02-08 23:52:20,791 TRACE org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.job.JobExceptionsHandler [] - Received request /jobs//exceptions.
2022-02-08 23:52:20,793 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.job.JobExceptionsHandler [] - Could not create the handler request.
org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.HandlerRequestException: Cannot resolve path parameter (jobid) from value "".
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.HandlerRequest.<init>(HandlerRequest.java:98) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.AbstractHandler.respondAsLeader(AbstractHandler.java:183) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.LeaderRetrievalHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(LeaderRetrievalHandler.java:83) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159) [?:1.8.0_312]
    at org.apache.flink.util.OptionalConsumer.ifPresent(OptionalConsumer.java:45) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.LeaderRetrievalHandler.channelRead0(LeaderRetrievalHandler.java:80) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.LeaderRetrievalHandler.channelRead0(LeaderRetrievalHandler.java:49) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.router.RouterHandler.routed(RouterHandler.java:115) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.router.RouterHandler.channelRead0(RouterHandler.java:94) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.router.RouterHandler.channelRead0(RouterHandler.java:55) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.FileUploadHandler.channelRead0(FileUploadHandler.java:238) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.FileUploadHandler.channelRead0(FileUploadHandler.java:71) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_312]
```

Comment: I get the same error. Any resolution? My app still runs, but ideally, I'd like to fix that and get rid of the error messages.